# If $X$ is binomial$(n,p)$, find unbiased estimator for $p^2$

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

So I know I'm looking to find a function $\delta(X)$ so that $E\left[\delta(X)\right] = p^2$.

Let me venture a guess that $\delta = \hat{p}^2 = \frac{x^2}{n^2}$. Then:

$$E\left[\hat{p}^2 \right] = E\left[ \frac{x^2}{n^2} \right] = \frac{1}{n^2} E\left[x^2\right] = \frac{1}{n^2}\left[Var(X) + E[X]^2 \right] = \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{p(1-p)}{n} + n^2p^2 \right)$$.

So is it ok to say that an unbiased estimator is: $$ \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{p(1-p)}{n} + n^2p^2 \right)-p^2?$$

I'm not feeling confident in this answer since I haven't really taken a statistics class before, so I'm very new to this.

Comment: Your answer cannot be an estimator since it depends on the value of $p$.

Answer (score 4):

Your estimator should be of the form $\delta(X)$, as you say -- your expression is not, as written it actually assumes you already know $p$.

**Outline:** the variance of the binomial will be $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = np(1-p) = np - np^2$.

Since you want $p^2$, you may rewrite this as
$$
p^2 = \frac{1}{n}\left( np - \operatorname{Var}(X) \right) = \frac{1}{n}\left( \mathbb{E}[X] - \operatorname{Var}(X) \right).
$$
Do you know any unbiased estimators for respectively $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and  $\operatorname{Var}(X)$? If so, can you combine them to get one for $p^2$?

Comment: What sort of parameters am I allowed to have in my answer (e.g. $n$ is allowed but $p$ is not)? In class we showed an unbiased estimator for $E[X]$ was $\hat{p}$. We didn't prove one for the Variance but I would guess that it would be $\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}$

Comment: You cannot use in your estimator the value you are trying to estimate -- and since knowing $p$ is equivalent to knowing $p^2$, that means no using $p$ itself. AFAIK, usually one assumes knowledge of $n$ (I don't know if that's really required, but that is the easiest scenario)

Comment: So I can't use $p$ but I can use $\hat{p}$? So it sounds like I can have an unbiased estimator of $p^2$ to be: $\frac{1}{n}\left( \hat{p} - \frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n} \right)$? Or do I need to expand $\hat{p}$ into $\frac{x}{n}$ since that seems to be more aligned with the form $\delta(X)$

Comment: @Brenton The simplest is just to combine (linearly, using the idea/expression above) two unbiased estimators, resp. for the mean and the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance). It is easy to check that a linear combination of unbiased estimators for two quantities will be an unbiased estimator for the same linear combination of these quantities.